# Does bcache require a fresh installation?

Tags: ssd, bcache

Because my notebook has a SSD and a HDD, I want use the SSD as cache just like Rapid Storage in windows. I find bcache offers this functionality so I decide to try it.

I got bcache and bcache-tools via git then followed the guide at:

http://evilpiepirate.org/git/linux-bcache.git/tree/Documentation/bcache.txt

```
Getting started:
You'll need make-bcache from the bcache-tools repository. Both the cache device
and backing device must be formatted before use.
  make-bcache -B /dev/sdb
  make-bcache -C -w2k -b1M -j64 /dev/sdc
```

Does that mean I have to format the whole HDD to enable the bcache?

Comment: Related question: [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252140/88802)

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for a fresh install.  See the blocks README and the [bcache FAQ](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/FAQ/).  To enable bcache on your root filesystem, you would [convert the root device with `blocks`](https://github.com/g2p/blocks#converting-your-root-filesystem-to-bcache), whether or not you have a fresh install.

ObDisclaimer:  I wrote the conversion tool.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that mean I have to format the whole HDD to enable the bcache?

That's certainly what is suggested, yes. This is fairly common in RAID-like situations. You start by generating a new mapped bcache device and then you format *that*, instead of the hardware directly.

However, the other RAID-like things (mdadm, dmraid, etc.) have documentation that make it quite clear how you create one of these setups and then install on top of it (and have `initramfs` load the right stuff so you can boot!)

I'm *fairly* experienced messing around with bizarre file system arrangements and kernel modules, but even I wouldn't want to touch this, especially not if I was trying to retrofit it into an existing installation.

I would concentrate on what I've got in front of me. If your SSD is fast and of a moderate size ~10GB+, stick Ubuntu on there and host `/home` on the spinning rust. That should give you some room for installing things, though you might have to move `/opt` to rust at some point. It may seem complicated now, but it's quite easy to split an installation over multiple disks.

If the SSD is tiny (<8GB) and/or slow, it may be worth considering just not using it.

Comment: My SSD is 32G and it run quite well in Rapid Storage on windows. But I still confused about bcache. Is there any one who has tried bcache?

Answer (score 0):

Another option that don't require you to do a fresh install (given that you use ext3 or 4) is to move the journal to ssd, and add data=journal for the different filesystems you have. For the rootfilesystem this has to be added as a kernel parameter rootflags=data=journal .

More about this can be read on http://insights.oetiker.ch/linux/external-journal-on-ssd/

Comment: You should probably enable [`journal_async_commit`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) to make this fast. Unless you boot really old kernels, this option is a good thing to have even for single-disk ext4.