# How should I partition my new SSD? (Journaling on another HDD?)

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ssd

I know this might seem a strange question and I know I should buy a good UPS but I already had had two of them and none of them did a good job. I'm living in a house where many power outages occur (please, don't ask me why...) so data loss risk is very high. I bought a new SSD but I'm planning to keep my old HDDs, so I thought about this configuration:

```
/ on SSD (ext4 of course)
/var on HDD
/tmp on HDD
/swap on HDD (swappiness set to 1 since I have 4 GB of RAM)
scheduler = deadline or noop (can you point me a good way to do this permanently?)
journaling = enabled (due to the power losses I can't just disable it but is it possibile to store the journal on another HDD? If yes, how?)
discard and noatime in fstab
```

What do you think about that?

The SSD I bought is a Samsung 120 GB 840 series and my mainboard supports SATA2. Is it really needed to put var, tmp and cache on another HDD? What if I just install the whole system on my SSD, how many time do you think it will last?

Thank you so much and sorry for the odd question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry, have totally overseen your comment. sometimes I am blind.

I don't know what you are using in your home-directory. But I would then put any folder resp. Partition on to your ssd and then put /home onto your normal hard-disk-partitions.
for example it is good when /tmp-folder has a size not smaller than 4.7 GB, because then burning dvds has no trouble with sizes like 4.3 or 4.7 GB - discs.
swap-partition too on your ssd.

I myself have all partitions on 120 GB - ssd and I don't use loads of graphics, games or music files in my home-folder - so there is still space for about 30 Gibi left. But 120 GB would be too small if you plan to install windows too.

Comment: Please edit your existing answer or reply in a comment rather than add another answer.

Comment: @psusi - yes I know about when to comment and when to answer. On 6th June was something up, and was not able to edit it all into 1 answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use gparted-program - it is given in ubuntu-live-CD.
easier for you.

in gparted you need first to create a partition-table - in case
you later need to rescue/recover your hard-disk (a rescue can fail when partition-table
is not created before that)

(if you want to be proof against hack-attacks you can leave away partition-table, but
then later you can have trouble if rescue/recover is necessary).

so you have now a partition-table created with gparted (look there in menu...)
you need (allowed are only 4 partitions - except: you create logical partitions,
but here you dont need logical partitions (harddisk is too small))
1 swap-partition (=size of 2xRAM file-system:swap) 8 Gibi (8x1024 MB)
1 /tmp-partition (file-system: ext4) about 10 Gibi is sufficient ( 10x1024 MB)
1 /-partition (for root - file-system: ext4) (30 Gibi is enough)
1 /home-partition (file-system:ext4) (rest for home is enough)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, dschinn1001. So you're suggesting to put /home on the HDD too? I have 3 hard drives (2x320 GiB and 1x500 GiB) and I sure could find some space to store my home, but since my SSD is 120 GiB, I guess I could put my home there too or is it better to avoid that? Moreover, I would like to keep the journal while storing it on another HDD, is it possibile? And how can I set the scheduler in a "proper" way? Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your partitions as they are, and use the SSD to cache them.  See [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd/340059#340059)