# How to Prepare this SSD for Ubuntu 13.04 in Zenbook?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 13.04, ssd

I have a new Asus Zenbook UX32V with:

- 24GB Sandisk SSD
- 500Gb Hitatchi

It came with Windows 8 but I've successfully installed Ubuntu 13.04 dual boot and everything works great. Now I've spent some time with it and loving Ubuntu (and hating win 8) I would like to go back and ditch the dual boot and just run Ubuntu. Boot time is sluggish and I really hate and have no need for windows 8.
Looking at the disks tool on Ubuntu I can see I have the above drives, the SSD seems to be taken up with:

- IntelRST 6.4Gb (mountable)
- HST 18Gb (Unknown)

Meanwhile the 500Gb regular drive is filled with 9 partitions:

- system
- recovery
- microsoft reserved
- Win 8 OS
- Data
- Ubuntu file system
- Linux swap file
- restore

So basically I suspect Ubuntu is not using the SSD at all. I'd like to delete all partitions on the 24Gb SSD and try format it then try and install Ubuntu on that. I've heard however this is meant as a cache drive and shouldn't be used for file system?

Is is safe to use Ubuntu 13.04 on the whole SSD disk?

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX32V
Ubuntu: 13.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partitions on the SSD look like Intel's version of RAID/SSD caching technology. Whereas the partitions on the HDD look like a bunch of Windows/recovery/Ubuntu partitions. I'm considering a similar laptop and given what I've research what I would do is:

- Install Ubuntu normally telling it to take over the whole HDD
- Repartition the SSD to have a single partition and then use bcache for it: [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd)

This will use the HDD for all storage and yet use the SSD to speed it up as a cache. This is the basic config. It will be more complex if you want Ubuntu installed with separate partitions on the HDD (e.g., /home separate from /) or if swap should be on the SSD.