# Can I install Intel Smart Response Technology?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, intel

I have 1 500gb HDD and 64gb SSD in the system. I already installed Ubuntu in my system on the HDD.

Can I have Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology) without sacrificing my Ubuntu?

Comment: Why did you install it on the HDD in the first place? 64GB of SSD is *plenty* of space for Ubuntu OS + homedir. Then put all bulk data on the HDD.

Comment: Because over the time.. I dont want to waste time transfer up and forth between hdd and ssd. Plus.. Ssd got a limit where it always break after the write erase limit. N i already damaged one after a two years of usage due to the fact i used matlab. It tooks a lot of space to keep all my laborataries data.

Answer (score 2):

No.  If you want SSD cache-ing you can use bcache as noted in some other questions on site.  Intel SRT is a Windows only technology, but bcache is in software not hardware and supposedly provides similar performance gains.

Comment: I found out this about intel rst and linux kernel. it said we can use mdadm program http://intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020663.htm

Comment: mdadm is for Raid as far as I am aware, not for cache-ing.

Comment: Correct me if im wrong, but for caching to be done.. We must raid the ssd 1st right? I bought this motherboard n ssd with all great feature it said it can give. If it cant be exploited fully by using ubuntu, should i consider swapping onto windows?

Comment: No.  You're falling victim to selective hearing.  Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd

Comment: @hbdgaf Also read the link provided by aknelkaiser. It clearly shows Intel states that you can use `mdadm` and `dmraid` for Intel RST technology. I'm not aware of that and it seems very unlikely this is correct. It also lacks how exactly to use these utilities for RST. As far as I know they are *not* compatible with other than standard fake-RAID from Intel.

Comment: Every guide I've seen recommends turning of intel RST.  Their website saying use raid to use our stuff and contact your vendor instead of providing at least one use case example sounds a lot like, if you pay intel they'll tell you how it works.  I'm not okay with that.  Moving on.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently not, I copy from [Intel site](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm) (first result on Google):

> System Requirements
>
> ...
>
> Operating system: Microsoft Windows 8* or Windows 7 (32-bit  and 64-bit editions)

Comment: I found out this about intel rst and linux kernel. it said we can use mdadm program http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-020663.htm

Answer (score 0):

[ISRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology) is easily confused with [IRST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Rapid_Storage_Technology)!
The Linux kernel currently(3.15) only supports the latter one through its `imsm` module.

Trying to access fake-Raid-drives formatted in the SRT way gets rejected my `mdadm`:

```
mdadm(IMSM): Unsupported attributes: 2000000
mdadm: Unsupported attributes in IMSM metadata.Arrays activation is blocked.
```

Fedora [suggests](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=890881#c57) to drop the metadata of the fake-Raid in order to make the additional device usable within linux.

Comment: Note, that the work of Dan Williams https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1040362#c1 has neither been merged into the [Kernel](https://github.com/djbw/linux/tree/isrt) nor `mdadm` by now.