# What is the best way installing Ubuntu on an 1 SSD + 2 HDD combination?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, ssd

I have installed, already, ubuntu (latest) on [SSD OCZ Vertex 4](http://ocz.com/consumer/vertex-4-sata-3-ssd/specifications) (everything, home, tmp, /, swap, etc).

I have two other HDDs. One is just Windows (used by my wife, only) and one is used to just store big media files (300GB each).

Someone told me that `swap` and `tmp` files will wear out my SSD. Is this true?

Having this installation, what should I do now, in order to protect my SSD?

Comment: If you fear to wear out your SSD, don't use it. Put it in a box somewhere and don't use it. If you actually want to use the speed of the SSD just install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: If you go with bcache: http://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even continual writing on modern SSDs (which yours is) will still get tens of years of life before things start deteriorating. On OCZ drives there's also an overhead the controller uses to swap out bad sectors to further enhance the lifetime.

That's not to say that faults don't happen before then but that's true of all hardware, and let's be honest here, mostly true of mechanical disks.

I wouldn't be too concerned. Back things up as usual (when SSDs "go", they really just stop working so there's no freezer or knocking option to restabilise the platters) and you'll be fine.

Minimising swap usage is just generally good business. Add RAM if you're swapping lots.

And once you have a load of RAM, mounting /tmp with `tmpfs` (a RAM-based cache) is generally a good idea. I've added this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
tmpfs       /tmp        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777  0   0
tmpfs       /var/tmp    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777  0   0
```

That'll have the added bonus of speeding things up, but it does require you have enough RAM or you'll just be swapping to disk (and that's much slower).

Comment: Thank you. That was very informative. 4 Gigs of RAM is enough? I can get more if you think would be better. That is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I can't prescribe an exact amount. It really depends on your usage. I'm a bit of a blip on the "normal usage" scale... On my desktop I have 24GB total, 5-20GB in use depending on what I'm doing. My swap is usually empty.