# Help me setup my new build!

Tags: compiling, ssd

Background:

- Linux user for about 2 years
- More of a GUI guy than a terminal guy, but I can `sudo apt-get
  install program-name`
- Don't know how to compile or install from `.zip/tar` files. If there
  are menus I'm good.
- I use UbuntuStudio, prefer XFCE as it's faster and don't like desktop
  effects.

I just purchased these parts to make my first ever build: http://pcpartpicker.com/p/1HCyb

My first priority is video editing with KDEnlive. Light gaming on the side.

**My concerns:**

- This will be my first experience with SSD for the OS. Is there
  anything different I need to do with setup? I will also have a 1tb
  storage drive. Is it better to have the OS on the SSD and the Home
  folder on the storage drive or have it all on the SSD?
- Is this new graphics card plug and play? Or will I have to compile
  drivers?
- Does anyone recommend any specific settings when installing
  UbuntuStudio on the new system?

Sorry if the questions sound dumb. I have 4 more days until the new parts come in so I would like to be as prepared as I can be.

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Use [hybrid storage](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd), it works pretty well.

Comment: please ask only one question per question...

Comment: Asking more than one question at a time does not work well on this site as somebody who can answer one question may not be able to answer all of them.  I'm voting to close this question but suggest you ask these questions separately.

Answer (score 2):

I would install the system on the SSD. Rule of thumb for placing data on the SSD:

- Often accessed data, lots of small files (as the search speed on SSDs is great)
- OS (if you want fast boots and a responsive system)
- The cache of your favorite browser

Data i would NOT store on a SSD:

- Large chunks of files (SSD space is expensive, and if the data is aligned in a block, new normal HDDs are very fast)
- Memory that is not accessed often.

I also suggest you not fill up your SSD to the upper limit.

That being said, i would also store the `/home` partition on the SSD. I would install the games on the other drive, as nowadays they use loooots of space.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to have the OS on the SSD and the /home partition on the storage drive. In this way the OS will load faster, and all your "storage files" like documents, downloaded files etc will be stored on the HDD. I also suggest you to use the SSD for the project files of KDEnlive and (you said light gaming, so I assume you're going to install steam) make a Steam Library on the SSD so these files, kdenlive project and games, will load faster.

About the video card, (ATI/AMD 7870), for the driver you can use either opensource radeon driver (used and installed by default) or fglrx (AMD Catalyst). If you want to install the proprietary fglrx driver you don't have to compiler any .zip/tar file, and you can follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI