# Flashcache on Xubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ssd, flashcache

First of all, I'm noob on using flashcache, and all that I'll post here is studying about it.

I've an Asus K56CM, i5 with 500gb of HD and 24Gb of SSD for cache. In windows 8, the default operating system, uses Expresscache for caching the HD in the SSD.

I want to make the same in Xubuntu, and i've seen Flashcache as the better way to do this.

I've follow several manuals, but I'm loosing something.

The partitions table is:

```
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 

├─sda1   8:1    0   5,9G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2   8:2    0 117,2G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0 342,7G  0 part /home

sdb      8:16   0  22,4G  0 disk 

├─sdb1   8:17   0   250M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sdb2   8:18   0   5,9G  0 part 
└─sdb3   8:19   0  16,3G  0 part
```

SDA is Hard Disk and SDB is SSD

In SDB2 I'm using gdisk for Intel Rapid Boot, and I want to cache /home in SDB3.

The walkthrough I've follow is (http://nitocris.over-blog.net/article-flash-cache-as-home-or-root-on-ubuntu-109792445.html):

```
 - apt-get install git-core
 - mkdir -p ~/Build/ ; cd ~/Build/
 - git clone https://github.com/facebook/flashcache.git
 - sudo apt-get install git build-essential dkms linux-headers-`uname -r` uuid-dev
 - cd flashcache
 - sudo make -f Makefile.dkms all boot_conf
 - sudo make install
 - sudo modprobe flashcache
 - sudo echo "flashcache" >> /etc/modules
 - dmesg | tail
```

And Flashcache is now installed. But my problem is when I create the flashcache link.

I take the UUID of SDA3 and make the flashcache_Create on SDB3:

```
- umount /home
- flashcache_create -p back home_cached /dev/sdb3 /dev/disk/by-uuid/XXX-XXX (the ID)
```

And then, I edit the FSTAB, commenting the /home mounting and adding:

```
- /dev/mapper/home_cached /home     reiserfs defaults        0       2
```

Everything ok, but now, then when I reboot system, /home is not being mounted... and I don't know why...

Any help?

THanks!

PD: sorry about my english, i'm spanish :S

EDIT: Ok, I have the solution. Flashcache must be created on every reboot, so I have created an script to execute on boot. I described it here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179297

Comment: Hmmm... I've seen the problem... When I reboot, the Mapper is deleted... and don't know why :S

I've read in some sites that putting writeable is the solution... but isn't another solution?

Comment: Solution found: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2179297

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; I came up with this upstart conf file which will find all flashcache drives and load them, then set sysctl settings for the drives, and then mount them.  If you add more drives, all you need to do is add them to /etc/fstab and make sure they have the option nobootwait in the fourth field, e.g.

> /dev/mapper/export /export ext4 nobootwait 0 1

Here's the file, which should go into `/etc/init/flashcache.conf`:

```
# flashcache - Set up flashcache devices and mount them

description "Set up flashcache devices and mount them on boot"

start on mounted

task

console output

script
    # Load any flashcache devices and get them ready to mount, then set sysctl settings.

    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

    # Load up any flashcache devices
    for P in /dev/disk/by-id/*; do
        if flashcache_load $P 2>/dev/null; then
        echo "Loaded flashcache device from $P"
        fi
    done

    # Now look through all WRITE_BACK devices and set the sysctl settings
    for d in $(dmsetup table | grep 'cache mode(WRITE_BACK)' | perl -pe 's@.*ssd dev \(/dev/disk/by-id/(.*?)\), disk dev \(/dev/disk/.*?/(.*?)\).*@$1+$2@'); do
        # disable writing dirty cache data at shutdown
        sysctl -w dev.flashcache.$d.fast_remove=1
        # change reclaim policy from FIFO to LRU
        sysctl -w dev.flashcache.$d.reclaim_policy=1
        # do not write "stale" data to disk until evicted due to lack of space
        sysctl -w dev.flashcache.$d.fallow_delay=0
    done

end script
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to:
[How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd)

There are 2 cases to make/configure your flashcache:

1. Caching your root device, or
2. Caching a non-root (not mounted at `/`) device