# SSD cache for Lenovo Y500

Tags: lenovo, ssd, cache, 13.10, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Y500 with a dual GTX650M, 16Gb SSD and 1Tb HDD.

I just install a clean Ubuntu 13.04 then upgrade to 13.10. Previously I had windows 8 but I cleaned it off and only use Ubuntu 13.10 since then.

What I'm trying to ask is that:

Is there any SSD cache out of the box for Ubuntu 13.10 or do I have to manually enable them by using flashcache/dm-cache/bache/etc ?

My current setting of SSD in my BIOS is AHCI and Y500 AFAIK doesn't have RAID option. So is there anything I can do to have an alternative to Intel Smart Response technology that is available in Windows 8?

Lastly, would it be better if I just install /root on the SSD with /home on HDD? Will there be any performance improvement using this set-up instead of SSD Cache?

Thank you in advance for your help. Since I'm very new to Ubuntu, some links to existing tutorials or informations will be so much appreciated.

Comment: Related question: http://askubuntu.com/q/731612/40581

Answer (score 0):

I have similar hardware configuration in my Asus k56cm, and same questions.

I tried to use flashcache, but I'm having problems. You can see in my historical questions.
[Flashcache on Xubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354411/flashcache-on-xubuntu-13-04)

The better solution I found is using flashcache, instead the others, because kernel recompilation is not necessary, but having only 24gb in the ssd, I think that caching /root is too large. I think the better thing is cache /home