# What should I use my SSD for?

Tags: server, raid, ssd, email, lvm

I am setting up a small (1 user) email server. So far I have put in 2 x 1TB WD Red drives and set them up for LVM with RAID1 mirrored LVs.

I also picked up a 120GB Samsung 840 Evo but I can't figure out what to use it for.

I read that they recently added SSD caching to LVM in kernel mainline but I imagine it will be a year or two before that reaches Ubuntu.

What should I use it for then?

Should I get a second one for RAID so I can move the root (non-home) files to it for faster performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well [`bcache` is an option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd) on 14.04.

`dm-cache` (for which `lvmcache` is apparently just a friendly frontend) [seems faster according to benchmarks](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1306.1/01246.html) but [seems quite painful to use directly](http://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/2013/06/30/ssd-caching-using-dmcache-tutorial/). That should still be an option if you like, but it's a slog.

You could manually update (or find a PPA for) `lvm2`. This package is largely just a toolchain for exploiting Kernel features so (with a pinch of salt and many backups) should be relatively safe to run on 14.04.

Comment: It looks like bcache is the one to use until lvmcache is available. Do you know if it is possible to delete the bcache superblock at a later date?

Comment: I honestly don't know. With any of these modern approaches I would thoroughly suggest testing it before you throw any real-world data on it. That includes testing to see what happens to the RAID1 if the cache device dies. You can emulate most of these in a virtual machine fairly easily but also test on hardware.