# Partioning a dual SSD & HDD latop, complete guide

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have bought a nice Asus Zeenbok, one with a 30GB SSD and a 500GB HDD.

Can anybody help me with a complete guide to partitioning the two? I can figure and judge the sizes myself, and I have tried one set-up, based on answers from similar questions in here, but it didn't work well, as I choose a few partitions rather randomly, in my lack of understanding all the partitions.

I would like to utilize the 30GB for Ubuntu and maybe the software I'm going to install, and I've realized that keeping all documents, /tmp and other data on the HDD would be better. I have no intentions to dual-boot with Windows, which I can see many similar questions ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple: `/` goes on SSD, `/home` goes on HDD. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend  you to use [bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/). It will use your `SSD` as caching device for your `HDD`. I thing that it is the best thing that `30GB SSD` can do.

Current [Ubuntu Distribution Installer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity) don't support creating bcache devices, so you need to install everything on `HDD` as usual, create empty partition on `SSD`. Then follow one of this tutorials:

- [1](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/754674-using-bcache-to-soup-up-your-sata-drive)
- [2](https://github.com/g2p/blocks#converting-your-root-filesystem-to-bcache)
- [3](http://www.wdong.org/wordpress/blog/2014/05/28/installing-ubuntu-14-04-to-bcache/)

Also read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/340059/164083) question