# Why do I have two disks and can I delete one?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, disk-usage

One is a SSD disk is too small only 14 GB I can't install all the editors I need like Unity, gimp and many more. It does not help completely with the symbolic links, it still needs space to download certain apps and node.js and much more.

[image]

The other one TB Hard disk is really big and I would need that space in the SSD disk. I have links to store images and other things to that disk but it is not enough space, I'm really desperate about it.

Comment: Your smaller drive is an M.2 drive.  You will have to upgrade to a larger one if you don't want to use that small of a SSD drive.  https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/97544/intel-optane-memory-series-16gb-m-2-80mm-pcie-3-0-20nm-3d-xpoint.html

Comment: I don't understand how I can upgrade to the larger one.

Comment: You would have to purchase a new physical M.2 drive if you want to upgrade to a larger one.

Comment: The SSD and the hard disk (HDD) are two different physical things. Think of one as a small sause pan and the other as a large frying pan. To upgrade, you have to buy a new larger sause pan. You cannot delete these. You have to open the computer and pull the SSD out and put a new one in.

Comment: I mean, you could create a separate partition on your HDD and install Ubuntu on to the hard drive but it won't be as fast. Hard drives are slow compared to solid state drives. M.2 drives are fairly inexpensive nowadays so it's probably a better idea to buy a larger M.2 drive.

Comment: How can I use it as it is? It is impossible to download editors and node js next js and all the rest I need on a computer. Thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: Is it better to reinstall windows again as I could work on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need Intel Smart Response when installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: Not really, I  already made symbolic links to my HDD disk. I have linked Desktop, all my app-images, pictures and I have moved LibreOffice and deleted Snap store as it took so much space. But I still can't download Unity games because there is  not enough space. I feel lost

Comment: It is a game engine, I make games. No you download it from here https://linuxhint.com/install-unity-2020-2-1f1-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: This question may work better for you. [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252140/how-do-i-install-and-use-flashcache-bcache-to-cache-hdd-to-ssd)